# Doubt in Off-Topic Question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions, off-topic

I would like to know why this question [Sniffing for iPhones](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93359/sniffing-for-iphones) was closed and this other question [How many GPS channels make sense?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11884/how-many-gps-channels-make-sense) my flag was declined.

The two question is really good question, I really want to know the answer, but not here in EE.SE. In my understanding the two questions are off-topic, the questions are asking about some doubt in use of a communication protocol.

I flagged wrong?

Comment: I'll add that voting to close is a privilege that you get with higher reputation because it takes a while to understand what is a good question. Sure you can try to short circuit that by flagging, but if you're having these questions I'm not sure that you should be flagging things for closing.

Comment: @W5VO - The question for me is that for me the question are very similar to each one, and one was closed with 5 votes of moderators and the other just the flag was declined. I just want to understand this. Even because 90% of my flags was helpfull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree 100% with Stacey's analysis, but when you say "I flagged wrong?" the best thing to do is just flag how you see fit at the time. As long as you're doing your best to try and improve the site at the time for a lot of things like that there's not really a wrong / right decision.

Even when you get direct close / re-open votes I've seen questions closed I think should have been left open and others I think should have been closed that are left open. Everyone will have a different opinion and that's the idea of everone apart from moderators needing five votes to close or re-open a question.

Comment: I will consider this in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The closed statement on the iphone question puts it well:

> "Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site
>   is intended specifically for questions on electronics design."

The reason why the GPS question is ok is because it is related to design. The question is essentially, "why is x designed this way?". The iphone one is not a design question.

Comment: In the GPS question also. Its just doubt about some subject that don't have anything with EE. At any moment appears to have some interest in design or develop something with it.

Answer (score 3):

The GPS question: say you want to build a GPS receiver. That's electronic design. The number of channels is one of the first questions you've got to ask yourself. This will determine which receiver module you will use in your **electronic design**.

Comment: I've got it, but I think the same think for the IPhone question.

Comment: @Butzke: I answered for the GPS because I can relate to that question. I don't have a specific opinion on the iPhone question.

Comment: @Butzke: hey, no offense. Some people confuse a downvote on EE (bad answer) with a downvote here (don't agree). But if the downvote is yours, and seeing your comment to Stacey's answer I'm getting the idea that you *desperately* want the GPS question closed. I wonder why. Why don't you follow Peter's advice, vote to close and let it be? Don't start a holy war over it. BTW, the GPS question got 5 upvotes today so far, so it looks like not everybody agrees with you.

Comment: You are wrong, no offense. I'm not making a war, I making a discusion, that the Meta is for. I already flagged that question, becuase that I'm here. I just want to know why two very similiar question one is closed and the other my flag was declined.